# Adding images to AVMutableCompositionTrack

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, avfoundation

I can use [`AVMutableCompositionTrack`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVMutableCompositionTrack_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to merge two video tracks together by simply calling `insertTimeRange:ofTrack:atTime:error:` and giving it an `AVAssetTrack`.

However, I have some video tracks *and* a few still images (jpg, png, etc) that I'd like to insert as still frames (with each image having a duration of a few seconds). I'm completely lost on how to insert the still images.

Is there no way to convert still images into an `AVAssetTrack` and insert them into an `AVMutableCompositionTrack`? Am I going to be forced into using the lower-level/more cumbersome (albeit more powerful) `AVAssetReader`/`AVAssetWriter`? If there was some way to add an image to an `AVMutableCompositionTrack` (and specify its duration) I'd really like to know how.

Comment: Do you have any updates on this?

Comment: @EvertonCunha: Nope. I really wish I did though. I even got a "Tumbleweed" badge for this question because it's gotten so little trafic. I wasn't able to get `AVAssetReader`/`AVAssetWriter` working either, unfortunately.

Comment: I have come across this http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums//viewtopic.php?f=20&t=3909&start=20#p24727 which might help us, please tell me of any progress and I will do the same